# Returning an array of Dates of posts in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to return an array of post dates in wordpress. So basically if I have 10 posts in wordpress, I need to create an array that will return the date that each of the tens posts were created. I don't need the list to be ordered nor contain any other content. Pretty simple right?!

Something like this:

```
$myarray = array();
query_posts();
// The Loop         
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $my_array = the_time('j');
endwhile;
```

I have attempted many different methods to accomplish this but they have all more or less failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `the_time` which does not return anything which is to display output directly.

use `get_the_time()`

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   $my_array[] = get_the_time('j');
endwhile;
```